# How many secret hats available in winter bash 2017

Tags: support, winter-bash-2017

I don't want to know the way to achieve it but may I know that how many of secret hats are available in total in this year of Winterbash

Comment: This is actually a cross-site dupe. It's probably better answered [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats)

Comment: Extensive coverage on all hats secret and otherwise for the stackexchange 2017 winter-bash found here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304340/winter-bash-2017-hats  And it includes a link to past years.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We don't know (it's *supposed* to be a secret). Past years show that about halfway Winterbash, when most secret hats are discovered, we poke one of the employees and ask if there are any more to be discovered yet. They usually respond truthfully.

Answer (score 10):

Secret hats are just that. Secret. The number of them won't be disclosed, and how to get them won't either until Winterbash wraps up for the year.

If we were to know how many there were, we would know when to stop, and that's no fun. The more mystery, the more fun it is trying to find them.